# Is there a regexp to match 2 char multiple times?

Tags: regex

I have a regex problem I can't seem to solve. The pattern is of 2 characters A and B. They can occour multiple times but change only once.

For example, I want to match

- AAABBB
- AABBBBB
- AAAA
- BBBBBB
- BBAAAA

but not

- ABAB
- AAABBBBA

Is there some regex pattern that can do this?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?
Please, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [`^(?:(\w)\1*){1,2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/QYyfKk/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```js
var patt = /(^A+B*$)|(^B+A*$)/

console.log(patt.test('AAABBB'));
console.log(patt.test('AAABBAA')) ;
console.log(patt.test('BBBBAAAA'));
console.log(patt.test('BBBB'))
```